# Read multiple csv files and write multiple netCDF files

Tags: python, loops, csv

I have the following Python code works perfectly fine for a single .csv file to convert for a netCDF file.

But, I have multiple files (365), as, 'TRMM_1998_01_02_newntcl.csv', 'TRMM_1998_01_03_newntcl.csv'....upto 'TRMM_1998_12_31_newntcl.csv'.

Can somebody help me to write to loop through all the csv files and create 365 netCDF files using this code.?

Anyhelp is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np

def convert_file(filename):
data = np.loadtxt(fname=filename, delimiter=',')
# filename = "TRMM_{}_{}_{}_newntcl.csv".format(d.year,d.month,d.day)
Lat_data = np.loadtxt('Latitude.csv', delimiter=',')
Lon_data = np.loadtxt('Longitude.csv', delimiter=',')

# create a netcdf Data object

with netCDF4.Dataset('TEST_file.nc', mode="w", format='NETCDF4') as ds:
    # some file-level meta-data attributes:
    ds.Conventions = "CF-1.6" 
    ds.title = 'precipitation'
    ds.institution = 'Institute'
    ds.author = 'Author'

    lat_arr = data[:,0] # the first column 
    lon_arr = data[:,1] # the second column 
    precip_arr = data[:,2] # the third column 

    nlat = lat_arr.reshape( (161, 321) )
    nlon = lon_arr.reshape( (161, 321) )  

    # ds.createDimension('time', 0)
    ds.createDimension('latitude', 161)
    ds.createDimension('longitude', 321)


    precip = ds.createVariable('precip', 'f4', ('latitude', 'longitude'))
    precip[:] = data[:,2]
    ## adds some attributes
    precip.units = 'mm'
    precip.long_name = 'Precipitation'


    lat = ds.createVariable('lat', 'f4', ('latitude'))
    lat[:] = Lat_data[:]
    ## adds some attributes
    lat.units = 'degrees_South'
    lat.long_name = 'Latitude'


    lon = ds.createVariable('lon', 'f4', ('longitude'))
    lon[:] = Lon_data[:]
    ## adds some attributes
    lon.units = 'degrees_East'
    lon.long_name = 'Longitude'    


    print ds


 # print filename

# load the data

path='C:\Users\.spyder2'
os.chdir(path)

d=datetime.date(1998,01,01)
while d.year==1998:
    d+=datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    convert_file("TRMM_{}_{}_{}_newntcl.csv".format(d.year,d.month,d.day))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use a [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects) object to loop through all of the days in a year. First, you should put the code you have in a function that takes a filename. Then, you can just make a `date` object and call the function in a loop:

```
import datetime
d=datetime.date(1998,1,1)
while d.year==1998:
    d+=datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    convert_file("TRMM_{}_{}_{}_newntcl.csv".format(d.year,d.month,d.day))
```

Comment: First of all, I don't know how to create a function file using my code posted above. I am very new to python. Then, I dont know how to use your code above to call that function I created. Can you show me as an example?

Comment: @user3408139 [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) is a basic tutorial on defining functions in Python. In my code, I used the function, assuming it's called `convert_file` and takes the name of the file to convert as its only argument.

Comment: OK. Do I need to save my code above as a function called "convert_file" and then run your code above? is that what you mean?

Comment: @user3408139 I'm not sure what you mean by "save...as a function". What you need to do is put the code you've written in a function called `convert_file` that takes the name of the file to convert as an argument, then put my code after it.

Comment: @user3408139 You need to indent function bodies. Also, you're setting `filename` to something else immediately.

Comment: I followed an online example and modified above but still it does not run. Can you correct me please or any hint?

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, there is an easier way of using os in this case. You can just take in the file names and use them in a loop:

```
import os

main_fp = "C:\\Users\\spyder2" 
path, dirs, files = os.walk(main_fp).next()

for f_path in files:

    data = np.loadtxt(f_path, delimiter=',')
    Lat_data = np.loadtxt('Latitude.csv', delimiter=',') #put lat and long csv's in separate folder, so you don't read them into the loop
    Lon_data = np.loadtxt('Longitude.csv', delimiter=',')

    #strip csv extentions
    new_fname = f_path.strip('.csv')


    with netCDF4.Dataset(new_fname+'.nc', mode="w", format='NETCDF4') as ds:
            # some file-level meta-data attributes:
            ds.Conventions = "CF-1.6" 
            ds.title = 'Non TC precipitation'
            ds.institution = 'AIR-Worldwide'
            ds.author = 'Dr. Dumindu Jayasekera'

        lat_arr = data[:,0] # the first column 
        lon_arr = data[:,1] # the second column 
        precip_arr = data[:,2] # the third column 

        nlat = lat_arr.reshape( (161, 321) )
        nlon = lon_arr.reshape( (161, 321) )  

        ds.createDimension('latitude', 161)
        ds.createDimension('longitude', 321)

        precip = ds.createVariable('precip', 'f4', ('latitude', 'longitude'))
        precip[:] = data[:,2]
        ## adds some attributes
        precip.units = 'mm'
        precip.long_name = 'Precipitation'

        lat = ds.createVariable('lat', 'f4', ('latitude'))
        lat[:] = Lat_data[:]
        ## adds some attributes
        lat.units = 'degrees_South'
        lat.long_name = 'Latitude'

        lon = ds.createVariable('lon', 'f4', ('longitude'))
        lon[:] = Lon_data[:]
        ## adds some attributes
        lon.units = 'degrees_East'
        lon.long_name = 'Longitude'   

        print ds
```

Comment: Where can I input the file names in the above code? My file names are: TRMM_1998_01_01_newntcl.csv, TRMM_1998_01_02_newntcl.csv upto TRMM_1998_02_14_newntcl.csv in the path specified by "C:\\Users\\spyder2".

Comment: The file names are taken from the files in the folder. Please experiment with the code; run the first part and print out f_path, those are your file names.

Comment: I ran the first 5 lines and I get this error below.                             Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-228-fa17243c8ab2>", line 8, in <module>
    data = np.loadtxt(path, delimiter=',')

  File "C:\Users\I54814\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 860, in loadtxt
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]

ValueError: could not convert string to float: rem *** Spyder Terminal History Log ***

Comment: You have changed the variable name, use f_path instead. As I said, experiment with the code, I don't come here often so it's useless to go through each line of code with you, as you'll be here all year at this rate.